# Is the Good Lich template is a character template or a lich template?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I'm confused a bit about the good lich template in Libris Mortis (pg. 156).

Is it a full template for character or it's a sub-template for the evil lich template (describe in Monster Manual) ?

I mean, to make a Good Lich character, does we have to apply evil lich template and after that, apply good lich template (and increase the Level Adjust to +5) ?
Or just apply good lich template (plus, of course, the undead template) and obtain a character with just +1 Level Adjust ?

Comment: "Are you a good lich, or a bad lich?" — Glinda, making her Knowledge: Religion check.

Comment: It's typically good not to accept answers too quickly before others get to put in answers that may improve upon the current answer

Comment: @ZeDemonPyro You think i should still wait a little bit more ?

Comment: It's fine this time, it's just a suggestion

Comment: Right, next time i'll be more patient ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's a variant on Lich**

Good Lich is a variant template; you alter Lich with the information found in Good Lich (and presumably remove the requirement to commit an act of 'unspeakable evil') and apply the resulting template to the character. Among other things, Good Lich increases Lich's CR and Level Adjustment, which would affect the character taking it as an option.

Comment: Thank you, i think you're right. It's interesting, this is the first time i see a sub-template for a monster-character template.
EDIT: _to commit an act of 'unspeakable evil'_ What i understood, for some fluff part around : A good lich is made by a divine/necro spark, in a temple, and need the blessing of the tutellar god of the character.

Comment: What about Good Lich bards? Wizards? Beguilers?

Comment: It's appear they have to convince a god (or, by the way, priests of this god) to help them for learn the good lich ritual (wich it's totally different from the evil lich ritual). I think, with some heavy search, a character (priest, wizard, bards, whatever) can find ritual informations and do it by himself.